# Check custom condition on every page with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to check for a condition on each page I visit on the website.

Basically, the user account's have a time limit, and if the user account has expired I need to redirect them to the renew page, this way they can log in to the system but can only access the renew page.

I could just make a function and call it on every action for every controller, but this doesn't make any sense, I could also do some hacking on bootstrap, but this doesn't seem the right solution also.

How can i do this the right way? Or maybe the bootstrap is the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve that is to add `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` to your application and implement the logic in the `preDispatch` method.

You will be able to do the checks and redirect the user with the Redirector helper.

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
$redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit('myaction', 'mycontroller', 'mymodule');
```

Comment: This is actually the cleanest and best solution, and I implemented it already. Thanks Florent

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking - as I have a lack of knowlegde of Zend - I'd say the Authentication layer/class/whatever would be the place to put this logic.

I assume there's a centralised place where you check the validity of the user session. You could easily add this extra condition to this place. If you maintain your access control in a different manner, bootstrap might be better.

Your options are always limited as your application probably has 1 single point of access, or at least a limited number of classes EVERY request goes through before presenting the page the user requested.

Be careful not to implement such conditions too strictly; make sure API requests (if any exist) won't get forwarded to the renew page, for example.

Comment: Actually since I'm using Zend Auth, they take care of validating user's and so on, I could extend the Zend Auth class, but first I have to figure how the Zend Auth works.

Comment: Extending the Zend Auth class sounds valid to me.